# Berks install SSL_Connect Certification Verify failed (Faraday:SSLError)

Tags: chef-infra, berkshelf, test-kitchen

As part of a cookbook(newbie) i am trying to write, i was using berks to install the dependencies from other cookbooks and eventually when i am running `berks install`, i am encountering certificate verification errors. Can any one help me to know what could be going wrong and how i could resolve this issue.Thank you

chef environment:

`Chef Development Kit Version: 0.12.0
chef-client version: 12.8.1
berks version: 4.3.0
kitchen version: 1.6.0`

berkshelf

`berks -v
4.3.0`

**berks install - Error**

```
/opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:46:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (Faraday::SSLError)
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:46:in `ssl_connect'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/ssl_socket.rb:24:in `create_socket'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:739:in `block in connect'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:91:in `block in timeout'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `call'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:735:in `connect'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:497:in `query'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:170:in `query'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1238:in `do_get_block'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.1/lib/httpclient.rb:1021:in `block in do_request'
from /opt/chefdk/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/httpclient-2.7.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Berkshelf with custom CA certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236213/use-berkshelf-with-custom-ca-certificate)

Comment: [Related or duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604784/chef-berkshelf3-proxy-settings-windows-platform/25605415#25605415)

Comment: @StephenKing I tried setting my environment variable to the /opt/chefdk/embedded/ssl/certs. when i ran `knife client list` i was getting  this error "WARNING: No knife configuration file found
WARN: Failed to read the private key /etc/chef/client.pem: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/chef/client.pem>
ERROR: Your private key could not be loaded from /etc/chef/client.pem"

Comment: Well, you haven't [configured knife](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html)..

Comment: Definitely a duplicate of that first one. Same answer applies.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`chefdk`](https://downloads.chef.io/chef-dk/) is a collection of tools bundled up together, though you do not have to use it, i don't, and you can bundle them together yourself.

i assume you have a `Gemfile` within your `chef` repository. if you don't, then you can easily create one by executing [`bundle init`](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html). now use the `Gemfile` to specify which [version](https://rubygems.org/gems/berkshelf) of [`berkshelf`](http://berkshelf.com/) you would like to use. once you have it, execute [`bundle install`](http://bundler.io/v1.11/bundle_install.html). if everything goes smoothly, `bundle exec berks configure` should work for you. you can configure it not to use ssl, or just place `~/.berkshelf/config.json` with the following content:

```
{
  "ssl": {
    "verify": false
  }
}
```

hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you @MrRoth. Turning down the ssl verification to false resolved my issue with downloading cookbook dependencies through berkshelf.

Answer (score 2):

Here, using berks 4.3.5, the following worked :

```
{
  "ssl": {
    "verify": false
  },
  "ssl.verify": false
}
```